# How can Univocity Parsers read a .csv file's data properly when there are lines at the end that are not part of the .csv data?

Tags: java, parsing, csv

How can Univocity Parsers read a .csv file's data properly when there are lines at the end that are not part of the .csv data?

Comments at the end of the file are parsed as if they are .csv data.

The code and stack trace are below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.*;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;


public class UnivocityParsers {

public Reader getReader(String relativePath) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath), "Windows-1252");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read input", e);
    }
}


public void columnSelection() {
    RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setSkipEmptyLines(true);

    // Here we select only the columns "Price", "Year" and "Make".
    // The parser just skips the other fields
    parserSettings.selectFields("AUTHOR", "ISBN");

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.parse(getReader("list2.csv"));

    List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();

    String[] strings = rows.get(0);

    System.out.print(strings[0]);

}


public static void main(String arg[]) {

    UnivocityParsers univocityParsers = new UnivocityParsers();

    univocityParsers.columnSelection();


}


}
```

Here is the file being parsed:

```
List of books by Author - Created today
"REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"
"1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",0345391802,5.95
"1990/01/12","Douglas Hofstadter",0465026567,9.95
"1998/07/15","Timothy ""The Parser"" Campbell",0968411304,18.99
"1999/12/03","Richard Friedman",0060630353,5.95
"2001/09/19","Karen Armstrong",0345384563,9.95
"2002/06/23","David Jones",0198504691,9.95
"2002/06/23","Julian Jaynes",0618057072,12.50
"2003/09/30","Scott Adams",0740721909,4.95
"2004/10/04","Benjamin Radcliff",0804818088,4.95
"2004/10/04","Randel Helms",0879755725,4.50

 **This is the top author list.
```

Comment: You mention a stack trace but I don't see one. Were you just talking about the file? Also what does the last row look like in parsed form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the input file you've given the following additional settings are required:

First:

```
    parserSettings.setNumberOfRowsToSkip(1);
```

This tells the parser to ignore the first row, otherwise it will use that as the header row.

Second:

```
    parserSettings.getFormat().setComment('*');
```

Your last line contains a comment starting with asterisk. This setting makes the parser skip lines with this sort of content.

This is all you need.